# Installing `qdap` - cannot install

Tags: r

I am trying to install `qdap` but I keep running into errors.

I have tried the following:

Method 1:

```
> install.packages("qdap")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/qdap_2.3.2.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3636513 bytes (3.5 MB)
downloaded 3.5 MB

package ‘qdap’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4eaFAF\downloaded_packages
```

So I think its successfully installed, then I run the following:

```
> library(qdap)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘qdap’:
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
```

Method 2:

Downloading the package from GitHub and manually installing it.

```
install.packages("C:/Users/MYUSER/Downloads/qdap-master.zip",repos=NULL)
```

Using devtools:

```
   > devtools::install_github("trinker/qdap")
Downloading GitHub repo trinker/qdap@master
These packages have more recent versions available.
Which would you like to update?

1: All                          
2: CRAN packages only           
3: None                         
4: tidyr (0.8.3 -> 1.0.0) [CRAN]
5: sys   (3.2   -> 3.3  ) [CRAN]

Enter one or more numbers, or an empty line to skip updates:
1
tidyr (0.8.3 -> 1.0.0) [CRAN]
sys   (3.2   -> 3.3  ) [CRAN]
Skipping 1 packages not available: Imports: chron
Installing 3 packages: Imports: chron, tidyr, sys
Installing packages into ‘C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Error: Failed to install 'qdap' from GitHub:
  (converted from warning) package ‘Imports: chron’ is not available (for R version 3.6.1)
```

Method: 3

```
    > install.packages("pacman")
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/USER/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/pacman_0.5.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 389806 bytes (380 KB)
downloaded 380 KB

package ‘pacman’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp4eaFAF\downloaded_packages
> pacman::p_load_gh(
+   "trinker/qdapDictionaries",
+   "trinker/qdapRegex",
+   "trinker/qdapTools",
+   "trinker/qdap"
+ )
Warning message:
In pacman::p_load_gh("trinker/qdapDictionaries", "trinker/qdapRegex",  : 
Failed to install/load:
trinker/qdap
```

Comment: You need to install jre. Read the help documentation for `rJava` package. That's the reason for "error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined"

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because having difficulties installing a package is a support issue. The poster should contact the authors. Stackoverflow is a programming site, for programming questions, not software installation support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As PavoDive mentioned, install jre. Check Oracle's website to get the latest version. Once you have installed, run the below snippet

```
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files\\Java\\<jre version>') # if you are using 64-bit R
Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Java\\<jre version>') # if you are using 32-bit R
```

Now, the packages that you tried to load should work just fine.